Tratamento de exceção em um sistema MVC
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema MVC com Java Spring Boot para controle e cadastro de produtores, mas estou em dúvida sobre como identificar as principais exceções que encontrarei e como tratá-las. Já fiz algumas pesquisas e vi que no Spring existem várias maneiras de lidar com exceções. Agradeço qualquer sugestão de artigos e livros que discutam o tema.

Existem diversas formas de lidar com exceções como você pontuou e uma das maneiras de identificar quais exceções lidar é entendendo do que se trata seu projeto: O que ele faz, para qual finalidade, o que ele precisa ter para que o objetivo seja alcançado. E está tudo bem se você não tiver tudo na cabeça, pois a outra forma de descobrir com qual exceção trabalhar é testando (Muitas vezes ocorre de percebermos um problema apenas testando nossa aplicação).
Como referência, você pode utilizar a documentação do próprio Java. Um livro bem conceituado, Effective Java de Joshua Bloch também aborda o tratamento de exceções em detalhes.
